# How can I use a temporary table I define in a subquery in a JOIN statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my code:

```
    SELECT 
<columns> 
FROM
(Subquery code) as relevantcustomers,
db_sales, 
JOIN relevantcustomers on relevantcustomers.id = sales.customer_id
```

Why doesn't SQL let me do this?

Comment: Can you show your actual sql code that's not working?

Comment: please post your tables and your exact code

Comment: because `sales .ne. db_sales` ? Plus: you have two entries in your range table with the name relevantcustomers.

Comment: You are mixing joins too. Use `JOIN` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
SELECT 
  <columns> 
FROM (Subquery code) as relevantcustomers, -- data from a subquery
db_sales, -- cross join a table named db_sales, but a comma too many
JOIN relevantcustomers -- joining a table called relevantcustomers
  on relevantcustomers.id = sales.customer_id -- conflict: which relevantcustomers?
```

You want:

```
SELECT 
  <columns> 
FROM (Subquery code) as relevantcustomers
JOIN db_sales on relevantcustomers.id = sales.customer_id;
```

Or the same with a `WITH` clause:

```
WITH relevantcustomers AS (Subquery code)
SELECT 
  <columns> 
FROM relevantcustomers
JOIN db_sales on relevantcustomers.id = sales.customer_id;
```